# AI IntelliCode doesn't work in VS 2022, fails to load model

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, intellicode

All my coworkers get fancy AI IntelliCode suggestions in Visual Studio 2022, but it doesn't seem to work at all for me. IntelliCode shows that it's enabled and ready:

[image]

When I try make it generate some suggestions for me, IntelliCode output shows this error:

```
[VSIX I] Trace log: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\VSFeedbackIntelliCodeLogs\20211119_064314_VS.log
[VSIX I] Version: 2.2.1835.37509
[Suggestions I] IntelliCode suggestions logging is enabled, you can disable logging in Options => IntelliCode => Advanced => IntelliCode suggestions logging
[Suggestions I] Logs will be written to C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\VSFeedbackIntelliCodeLogs\Suggestions\138030bc-17d4-4eaf-92db-bc6fc8c95ae9.
[ModelService I] Loading model for csharp intellisense-members from C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_9cf380bb\IntelliCodeModels\384B557F04AF6CC9B1F75609A1E18AD97EF3-771382CB40CE4452B936E5B1EB7D19B0.
[ModelService I] Loading model for csharp intellisense-members from C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_9cf380bb\IntelliCodeModels\6CB427AAAF1238BF7A384448C265176FE2D1-2D07A8A097F64029B4FBAF84EC8CAA7E.
[Suggestions I] IntelliCode suggestions language server has started.
[VSIX I] Removed 1 directory from C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\VSFeedbackIntelliCodeLogs\Suggestions
[PredictionManagerService I] Initializing rpc service connection.
[PredictionManagerService I] A model has not been loaded yet, requesting model load. 00:00:00.0278274 since initial attempt.
[ModelService I] Requesting model load on demand for all line-completion2.
[ModelService I] Requesting model load for all line-completion2.
[PredictionManagerService I] InitializeAsync duration was 00:00:00.0379794.
[PredictionManagerService I] No prediction available at 823 with suffix ''.
[ModelService I] Loading model for all line-completion2 from c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\intellicode\BundledModels\all_line-completion2.
[ModelService E] Failed to load model for all line-completion2 from c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\intellicode\BundledModels\all_line-completion2: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
   at BlingFire.BlingFireUtils.LoadModel(Byte[] modelName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.WholeLineCompletion.ModelInference.BlingFireTokenizer..ctor(String modelFile, String vocabFile, String analyzerName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.WholeLineCompletion.ModelInference.CodeGenerator.Initialize(String modelArchivePath, String modelExtractionPath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.ModelService.WholeLineCompletion.WholeLineCompletionModelCache.LoadFromFile(String modelPath, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.ModelService.Models.ModelCacheManager.LoadModel(String language, String analyzerName, String path, CancellationToken token)
[RpcModelServiceManager W] Error while trying to load model c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\intellicode\BundledModels\all_line-completion2: StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: External component has thrown an exception.
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__139`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.Core.RpcModelConsumer.<UpdateModelListAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
RPC server exception:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
      at BlingFire.BlingFireUtils.LoadModel(Byte[] modelName)
      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.WholeLineCompletion.ModelInference.BlingFireTokenizer..ctor(String modelFile, String vocabFile, String analyzerName)
      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.WholeLineCompletion.ModelInference.CodeGenerator.Initialize(String modelArchivePath, String modelExtractionPath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.ModelService.WholeLineCompletion.WholeLineCompletionModelCache.LoadFromFile(String modelPath, CancellationToken token)
      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.ModelService.Models.ModelCacheManager.LoadModel(String language, String analyzerName, String path, CancellationToken token)
      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.ModelService.ServiceTarget.LoadModelAsync(String language, String analyzerName, String path, CancellationToken token)
```

Answer (score 3):

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/AI-IntelliCode-doesnt-work-in-VS-2022/1591723

Microsoft has confirmed that the issue is caused by my name containing "ä" characters, which automatically makes my users home folder contain "ä" characters (when setting up Windows with Azure AD). No workaround or fix so far.